# How to resolve value error in Scipy function fmintnc?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am trying to implement coursera assignments in python, while doing Scipy optimise for logistic regression. However, I am getting the error below.

Can any one help!

**Note:** cost, gradient functions are working fine.

```
#Sigmoid function
def sigmoid(z):
    h_of_z = np.zeros([z.shape[0]])
    h_of_z = np.divide(1,(1+(np.exp(-z))))
    return h_of_z

def cost(x,y,theta):
    m = y.shape[0] 
    h_of_x = sigmoid(np.matmul(x,theta))
    term1 = sum(-1 * y.T @ np.log(h_of_x) - (1-y.T) @ np.log(1-h_of_x))
    J = 1/m * term1
    return J

def grad(x,y,theta):
    grad = np.zeros_like(theta)
    m = y.shape[0]
    h_of_x = sigmoid(x@theta)
    grad = (x.T @ (h_of_x - y)) * (1/m)
    return grad
#add intercept term for X

x = np.hstack([np.ones_like(y),X[:,0:2]])

#initialise theta
[m,n] = np.shape(x)
initial_theta = np.zeros([n,1])

#optimising theta from given theta and gradient

result = opt.fmin_tnc(func=cost, x0=initial_theta, args=(x, y))
```

> ```
> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 99 is different from 3)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I got it ! 
so the problem is fmin_tnc function programmed in a way we should parse the the parameter 'theta' before calling arguments x and y .
Since in my function 'cost' I have passed x and y first, it interpreted values differently so thrown ValueError .
Below are the corrected code..

```
    def sigmoid(x):
      return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

    def cost(theta,x,y):
        J = (-1/m) * np.sum(np.multiply(y, np.log(sigmoid(x @ theta))) 
            + np.multiply((1-y), np.log(1 - sigmoid(x @ theta))))
        return J


    def gradient(theta,x,y):
        h_of_x = sigmoid(x@theta)
        grad = 1 / m * (x.T @ (h_of_x - y))
        return grad

    #initialise theta 
    init_theta = np.zeros([n+1,1])

#optimise theta 
from scipy import optimize as op

result = op.fmin_tnc(func=cost,
                     x0=init_theta.flatten(),
                     fprime=gradient,
                     args=(x,y.flatten()))
```